# I have held broken packages when install wine on parrot os

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, wine, parrot-os

Hello everyone i want to install wine in parrot os but when i run the command :

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

this is the result

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~buster-1) E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i found some solutions use apt-add-repository and this package is not work in my dvice
when i use this package i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 276, in __init__
    self.refresh()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 292, in refresh
    self.matcher.match(source)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 484, in match
    if (re.search(template.match_uri, source.uri) and   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat", re.error: nothing to repeat at position 2
```

Comment: Remove the added repository and the package you added from it. It just seems it is not (yet?) compatible with your OS. If you are not an expert (true expert) on packaging and policies of your distribution, better not try to force things.